# Save dictionary as CSV

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking to change this dictionary:

```
{'GB00011785': ['The Shipyard, Bath Rd, Lymington SO41 3YL, United Kingdom'], 'GB00024511': ['17 Meadowbank Way, Eastwood, Nottingham NG16 3SB, United Kingdom', '73 Burton Rd, Withington, Manchester M20 1HB, United Kingdom']}
```

to: Note the duplicate GB00024511 with two addresses

```
{'GB00011785': ['The Shipyard, Bath Rd, Lymington SO41 3YL, United Kingdom'], 'GB00024511': ['17 Meadowbank Way, Eastwood, Nottingham NG16 3SB, United Kingdom'],['GB00024511':'73 Burton Rd, Withington, Manchester M20 1HB, United Kingdom']}
```

which I want to then export to a CSV to look like this:

```
Registration_Number   Address
GB00011785            'The Shipyard, Bath Rd, Lymington SO41 3YL, United Kingdom'
GB00024511            '17 Meadowbank Way, Eastwood, Nottingham NG16 3SB, United Kingdom'
GB00024511            '73 Burton Rd, Withington, Manchester M20 1HB, United Kingdom'
```

Does anyone know how I would go about it?

Currently my code produces this file:

```
GB00024511                                                   GB00011785 
['The Shipyard, Bath Rd, Lymington SO41 3YL, United Kingdom']  ['17 Meadowbank Way, Eastwood, Nottingham NG16 3SB, United Kingdom', '73 Burton Rd, Withington, Manchester M20 1HB, United Kingdom']
```

This is the code:

```
import csv
with open('AddressesFound.csv', 'w') as f:
     w = csv.DictWriter(f,dictionary.keys())
     w.writerow(dictionary)
```

Comment: `writerow` writes rows, but the first thing you write are the keys. So, write your items in the order you want them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys. Also, if you want to use `csv.DictWriter` you want *each row* to be a single dictionary mapping field names to values for that row.

You can first transform your original dict using a list comprehension:

```
source = {'GB00011785': ['The Shipyard, Bath Rd, Lymington SO41 3YL, United Kingdom'],
          'GB00024511': ['17 Meadowbank Way, Eastwood, Nottingham NG16 3SB, United Kingdom', '73 Burton Rd, Withington, Manchester M20 1HB, United Kingdom']}

csv_rows = [{'Registration_Number': key, 'Address': addr} 
            for key, value in source.items() 
            for addr in value]
```

Which produces this structure:

```
[{'Registration_Number': 'GB00011785', 'Address': 'The Shipyard, Bath Rd, Lymington SO41 3YL, United Kingdom'}, 
 {'Registration_Number': 'GB00024511', 'Address': '17 Meadowbank Way, Eastwood, Nottingham NG16 3SB, United Kingdom'}, 
 {'Registration_Number': 'GB00024511', 'Address': '73 Burton Rd, Withington, Manchester M20 1HB, United Kingdom'}]
```

You can then write out these rows fairly similarly to how you were trying:

```
import csv
with open('AddressesFound.csv', 'w') as f:
     writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ('Registration_Number', 'Address'))
     writer.writeheader()
     writer.writerows(csv_rows)
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

The following may help:

```
d1={'GB00011785': ['The Shipyard, Bath Rd, Lymington SO41 3YL, United Kingdom'], 'GB00024511': ['17 Meadowbank Way, Eastwood, Nottingham NG16 3SB, United Kingdom', '73 Burton Rd, Withington, Manchester M20 1HB, United Kingdom']}
```

Convert to a Pandas DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1, orient='index')
```

Save it as csv:

```
df1.to_csv('df1.csv', index=False)
```

To get the DataFrame in the desired format:

```
df2 = df1.stack().to_frame().reset_index(drop=False)
df2.columns = ['Registration', 'l1', 'Addresses']
df2.to_csv('df2.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @Ruthger just the other answer worked better for my scenario.

Comment: @Besarion: It is my pleasure!